# Need advise about loading screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview

could you show me some algorithm or example code to display like that picture with or with out animation

thanks for all advise

[image]

Comment: because this is fundamental to iphone development, I would recommend developer.apple.com.  baby steps are the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a semi-transparent view (regular view with black background with opacity = 80) that will cover the entire screen (in IB or in code), add a UIActivityIndicator and a label to the semi-transparent view, set it hidden.

If you use the IB then you should also create IBOutlets for the semi-transparent view (loadingView) and for the activity indicator (loadingAnimationIndicator)...

Use the next methods to show / hide the "loading view":

```
- (void)showLoading {
  [loadingAnimationIndicator startAnimating];
  loadingView.hidden = NO;
} 
- (void)hideLoading {
  loadingView.hidden = YES;
  [loadingAnimationIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```